# behind the scenes oAuth authentication with google docs API

Tags: android, google-docs-api

I'm developing a personal android app that needs to store a small amount of tabulated data in the cloud. Any cloud. So, I was thinking to use Google Docs Api to store this data in a spreadsheet.

I know this method was doable a few years ago but now google requires the app to use OAuth and from what I've read, this method  cannot work transparently without irritating the user. i.e. it has to go through AccountManager so the user will get some kind of popup asking for account info even though i want to use my own google docs account.

Is it possible to do the automatic oAUth exchange in the background with no user intervention??

Comment: No, this would allow to give an application silently access to a Google (or other) account and would be an enormous security risk.

Comment: having `android.permission.INTERNET` enabled is a security risk :)